# not able to keep the table hidden in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, vb.net

i have a probem where the table in a div tag called #viewPackage is appearing even though it should not trigger. My code is as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
       <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
       </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div id="grid">
      <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTireViewTypes"  DataSourceID="viewTypes" DataTextField="TireType" DataValueField="TireId" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="viewTirePackages_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Alle" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="viewTypes" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select TireId, TireType from tbl_mas_tire_settings where Tiresettingstype = 'Tiretype'"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvTirePackageList" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#4b6c9e" DataKeyNames="Seq_No" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvTirePackageList_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Seq_No" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="Seq_No"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="tirePackageNo" HeaderText="Dekkpakke" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="tirePackageNo"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="regNo" HeaderText="Regnr" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="regNo"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="custNo" HeaderText="Kundenr" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="custNo"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="custName" HeaderText="Kundenavn" ItemStyle-Width="200" SortExpression ="custName"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="Lokasjon" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="location"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="tireTypeDesc" HeaderText="Dekktype" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="tireTypeDesc"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="tireQualityDesc" HeaderText="Dekkvalitet" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="tireQualityDesc" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="tireDepthDesc" HeaderText="Dekkdybde" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="tireDepthDesc"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="regDate" HeaderText="Regdato" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="regDate"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="outDate" HeaderText="Forv. ut dato" ItemStyle-Width="20" SortExpression ="outDate"/>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="viewTirePackage" CssClass="viewTirePackageClass" Text="Vis" CommandName="viewTirePackage" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Seq_No")%>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="newTirePackageOrder" Text="Ny ordre" CommandName="newTirePackage" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Seq_No")%>' runat="server" width="60"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteTirePackage" Text="Slette" CommandName="deleteTirePackage" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Seq_No")%>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>

<div id="viewPackage">
    <span class="closePackage">X</span>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Dekkpakkenr:<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="viewTirePackageNo" runat="server" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            Regnr:<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="viewTireRegNo" runat="server" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Dekktype:<br />
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlEditTireTypes" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="TireType" DataValueField="TireId" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Velg..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select TireId, TireType, TireTypeVariable from tbl_mas_tire_settings where Tiresettingstype = 'Tiretype'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>
            Med/Uten pigg:<br />
             <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlEditTireSpikes" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="TireSpikes" DataValueField="TireId" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Velg..." Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select TireId, TireSpikes from tbl_mas_tire_settings where Tiresettingstype = 'TireSpike'"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
             <asp:button ID="btnEditTireSave" CssClass="closePackage" runat="server" Text="Oppdater" OnClick="btnEditTireSave_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The VB.NET code is as follows:

```
Protected Sub viewTirePackages_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlTireViewTypes.SelectedIndexChanged
     Call gvTirePackages()
     updatePanel1.Update()
End Sub
```

Where gvTirePackage() is filling in the gridview. I'm using jQuery to display/hide the table With the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#viewPackage').removeClass('animate visible').addClass('hidden');

   $('body').on("click", '.closePackage', function (e) {
       $('#viewPackage').removeClass('visible').addClass('animate hidden');
    });

    $('body').on('click','.viewTirePackageClass', function () {
        $('#viewPackage').removeClass('hidden').addClass('animate visible'); 
    });
});
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#viewPackage {
position: fixed;
width: 70%;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: #fff;
min-height: 100%;
left: 0;
}
#viewPackage.animate {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#viewPackage table {
margin: 10% auto;
}
.closePackage {
font-weight: 800;
float: right;
margin-right: 0.7em;
font-size: 2em;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

I using an updatepanel on the page. The gridview, aremaking the table we actually have hidden on pageload, appears when using the dropdown list. First Clue is to make this stop. Second is to make the linkbutton work in the same way, cause now it just appears witout the animation, which tells me it isnt working as it should. If you need to see more of the code, just let me know and ill paste it here or send it to you.

Thanks in advance for any tips or Clues!

Answer (score 0):

I made it work. What i did was to put in 2 updatePanels and have the updatepanel inside the div tag "virePackage". The div tag itself made it refresh so it jumped back again. Everything Works smooth now.